# How do I insert a JS script into a React class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need to insert a JS-script into the React class component and make the script run only at the moment when this component is already mounted and is physically in the DOM. How should I do it?
Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to execute a script or a function once your component is already mounted you should add a [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) in your React class component.

```
componentDidMount(){}
```

Comment: And what to write in it?

Comment: @Konstantin the JS-script you need